# Are "Is Wikipedia right" questions welcome?

Tags: discussion, scope, general-reference

I have previously asked:

> [How do we feel about "General Reference" questions that are somewhat answered on Wikipedia?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-do-we-feel-about-general-reference-questions-that-are-somewhat-answered-on#comment255_119)

The answers and comments to that question basically boiled down to two major points:

1. Asking a question that is answered (rightly or wrongly) on Wikipedia that can be answered by copy/paste from Wikipedia is a bad idea (too trivial, not enough research).
2. However, claiming that "this shouldn't be asked **because** Wikipedia has an answer - even if you indicate you already read the Wiki article - runs into a problem of Wikipedia being notoriously opinionated and subjective on politics related topics.

   <sub>My pwn personal pet example is "There is general consensus is that the right includes... nazis" quote - except that consensus only exists among people who generally don't identify themselves as "right". Surprise!</sub>

As such, do we welcome questions of the form:

> I have read [XYZ Wiki article](http://wikipedia.com/XYZ/), and upon reading it, I was not convinced that the following paragraph is correct (or properly referenced, or logically consistent with references, or simply unclear, pick one): {{include paragraph}}
>   Can some light be shed on that detail, and the seeming problem or unclear wording in the Wiki article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see any problem with questions of the type you suggest. Probably a good idea to give a brief explanation of the perceived problems in the quoted text, rather than simply an assertion of them, but perhaps that's implied and I'm just being over-picky.

Answer (score 6):

`Wikipedia being notoriously opinionated and subjective on politics related topics`

not exactly true.  That's easy to assume considering the nature of Wikipedia where all people are allowed to edit a page, but If you read a political Wikipedia article, and then venture outside of Wikipedia to read articles elsewhere, you will likely find that the Wikipedia article is the most unbiased of your findings.

---

but on topic, Even if there's a good Wikipedia article out there which addresses a particular question, It is very likely to be a lot broader and longer than a good answer, which should be  more concise and to the point(and perhaps more detailed too).  Wikipedia is a great resource, but It isn't a Q&A site.